# Javascript not opening 'chrome://newtab' with window.open event

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, tabs, window.open

I am trying to open a new tab in Google Chrome with a javascript window.open command. The function is tied to button in HTML. The button won't respond or even be able to be clicked.

```
function openTab() {
  window.open('chrome://newtab');
  window.open('','_self').close();
}
```

```
<button onclick="openTab()">button</button>
```

I do not see any errors in the code and it might have to do with the way that Chrome works. I also have tried running just the opening of the new tab. I have tried looking up this situation, but I have found nothing useful.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error: your onclick in HTML doesn't have () after it; your HTML code should look like the following:

```
<button onclick="openTab()">button</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that, but it still doesn't open

Answer (score 0):

I would provide a "return" in your function, even if just a false :

```
function openTab() {
  window.open('chrome://newtab');
  window.open('','_self').close();
  return false;
}
```

---

And a return in the call :

```
<button onclick="return openTab();">button</button>
```